# how to add different time present in a column of a gridview and show the sum in footer textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have some values (08:12,09:22,01:09) in a column(datetime) in a gridview
what i want is to get the sum of all values present in that column in a textbox which is present in the footer of that column.

i tried the below code -

```
    int hours, minutes;
    TextBox footxt = (TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("footxt1");
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
    {
        TextBox txts = (TextBox)row.FindControl("text11");

        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(txts.Text);
        hours = ts.Hours;
         minutes = ts.Minutes;
        hours += hours;
        minutes += minutes;
     footxt.Text = Convert.ToString(hours);
     }
```

but it doesnt work!

Comment: It doesn't work - how? Can you just explain exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TimeSpan's `operator +` :

```
TimeSpan total = new TimeSpan();
TextBox footxt = (TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("footxt1");
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    TextBox txts = (TextBox)row.FindControl("text11");
    total += TimeSpan.Parse(txts.Text);
}
footxt.Text = Convert.ToString(hours);
```

Comment: @MichaelCode, consider upvoting useful answers and accept answers that answer your question - if you plan to ask more questions having a lot of questions without accepted answers would lower chance to get good answer, so start early :)

Answer (score 2):

You can ty with - `hours and hoursCpt`

```
    ... 
    hours = ts.Hours;
    minutes = ts.Minutes;
    hoursCpt += hours;
```

So

```
int hours, minutes, hoursCpt, minutesCpt;
hoursCpt = 0;
minutesCpt = 0;

TextBox footxt = (TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("footxt1");
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    TextBox txts = (TextBox)row.FindControl("text11");

    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(txts.Text);
    hours = ts.Hours;
    minutes = ts.Minutes;

    hoursCpt += hours;
    minutesCpt  += minutes;
 }
 footxt.Text = Convert.ToString(hoursCpt + ((minutesCpt  - minutesCpt  % 60) / 60));
```

Comment: +1 for correct handling of overflow... but TimeSpan + is so much easier :)

Comment: i tried this but it giving me error on hoursCpt saying unassigned local variable ...i have taken int hoursCpt before foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're overwriting `hours` every time you loop through, so you'll add to it but then wipe it out when you come back to the next value.

```
int totHours, totMinutes
TextBox footTxt = (TextBox)GridView2.FooterRow.FindControl("footxt1");

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView2.Rows)
{
    TextBox txts = (TextBox)row.FindControl("text11");
    TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.Parse(txts.Text);

    totHours += ts.Hours;
    totMinutes += ts.Minutes;

}
footTxt.Text = totHours.ToString();
```